# Is there a way to exclude elements when importing a package?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am attempting to convert a .py file to a .exe file and there is an error with an element of a package that I am using (dfply). dfply has a sub-package called dfply.data is there a way to import everything but dfply.data?

I am currently using simply 
`import dfply as ply`

Comment: What is the ultimate purpose of not importing the subpackage?  If other parts of the package try to access it, you'll still have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you have access to the .py file you are importing from, you can try this:

First [define the `__all__`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) module

Add

```
__all__ = ["echo", "print" #Modules name go here
```

to the file which has these modules, or `__init__.py` of the package you want to import from.

Now

```
from module import *
```

imports *only* the specified modules in `__all__`